# How to draw current transformer in TikZ/CircuiTikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf, circuitikz

Trying to convert a sketch to a proper LaTeX diagram, and got stuck on the last component. Does anyone have a smart way to draw the current transformer between the transistor and interrupter?

Unfortunately, I am not allowed to post my code or the entire schematic due to a non-disclosure agreement.

I hope you can help me either way...

Sketch:

[image: current transformer]

My work so far:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage[europeanresistors,americaninductors,americanvoltage,smartlabels,siunitx]{circuitikz}


\ctikzset{bipoles/thickness=1}
\ctikzset{bipoles/length=0.8cm}
\ctikzset{bipoles/diode/height=.375}
\ctikzset{bipoles/diode/width=.3}
\ctikzset{tripoles/thyristor/height=.8}
\ctikzset{tripoles/thyristor/width=1}
\ctikzset{bipoles/vsourceam/height/.initial=.7}
\ctikzset{bipoles/vsourceam/width/.initial=.7}
\tikzstyle{every node}=[font=\small]
\tikzstyle{every path}=[line width=0.8pt,line cap=round,line join=round]
\usetikzlibrary{calc,quotes,babel,angles}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
(0,5) node[short,*-o,above] {+1000 V} 
to [short,o-o] ++(2,0)
to [short,o-o] ++(1,0)
to [open] ++(0.5,0)
to [short,o-] ++ (2,0)
 ++(0.63,0) node[nigbt,scale=0.8,rotate=-90,yscale=-1,name=igbt1]{} ++ (1,0)

(igbt1.E)++(0.1,0) -- ++(0,-0.3) to[D*] ($(igbt1.C)+(-0.1,-0.3)$)--++(0,0.3);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: So Far]

Comment: You appear to be missing the start of the \draw.

Answer (score 1):

Will this do?

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage[europeanresistors,americaninductors,americanvoltage,smartlabels,siunitx]{circuitikz}


\ctikzset{bipoles/thickness=1}
\ctikzset{bipoles/length=0.8cm}
\ctikzset{bipoles/diode/height=.375}
\ctikzset{bipoles/diode/width=.3}
\ctikzset{tripoles/thyristor/height=.8}
\ctikzset{tripoles/thyristor/width=1}
\ctikzset{bipoles/vsourceam/height/.initial=.7}
\ctikzset{bipoles/vsourceam/width/.initial=.7}
\tikzstyle{every node}=[font=\small]
\tikzstyle{every path}=[line width=0.8pt,line cap=round,line join=round]
\usetikzlibrary{calc,quotes,babel,angles}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[thin] (0,0) to[push button,*-] ++(1,0)
--  ++(2,0) coordinate[midway] (TT)
 node[nigbt,rotate=-90,yscale=-1,name=igbt1,anchor=C]{}
(igbt1.E) to[short,*-] ++(0,-0.3) to[D*] ($(igbt1.C)+(0,-0.3)$) to[short,-*] ++(0,0.3);
\draw[thin] (TT) ++(-.5,.2) to[cute inductor,name=L1] ++(1,0);
\draw (TT) ellipse[x radius=.4, y radius=.2]{};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: demo]